# What's the best way to scale millions of DNS queries.. (Python)

Tags: python, dns, dmarc, dnspython

Consequently, I initially intended to write this in Python, but I am completely open to writing it in any language.

I'm working with the Alexa top 1 million right now, and I want to find out how many of these domains have DMARC enabled. To obtain the TXT record on the "*dmarc*" subdomain, I am making use of [DNS Python](https://www.dnspython.org/). This is version 1, and when I have enough time, I will eventually parse it and load it into a Dynamo Table or Postgres (TBD) database. Time is a big factor because this data set will grow in the future.

The current code, which I have gotten down to the quickest, can be found below. It takes approximately 26 hours to run due to its 440 queries per minute. I want to write that down as much as I can.

I considered breaking this up into batches and starting those at the same time, but if I wanted to seriously cut down on time, I would have to do more than 100 batches. Naturally, the number of batches would also increase as this data set expanded)

```
import csv
import tqdm
from utils.dns import DNS
from concurrent import futures

with open('../data/top-1m.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    domains = [domain for _, domain in reader]

def runDNS(domain):
    return DNS().query(f"_dmarc.{domain}", "TXT")

# generate a tqdm progress bar for domains
with tqdm.tqdm(domains, total=len(domains), desc="Check DMARC") as tqdm_domains:
        with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=600) as executor:
            for domain in zip(domains):
                executor.map(runDNS(domain[0]), domain)
                tqdm_domains.update(1)
```

Comment: Are you CPU bound, network bound, or being throttled by your DNS server?

Comment: @tadman - From what I can see I am not seeing any limits. Checked my logs, from the DNS utils function and I am not seeing any network related timeouts or DNS rate limiting.

I am using 1.1.1.1 as DNS Resolver, and I have a timeout set to 1 second for the DNS query.

Comment: You'll need to find out what your bottleneck is before trying to optimize it. I've done similar things in Rust, [Tokio is fantastic](https://tokio.rs), but did hit limits with sockets first, as TCP DNS resolution can be very resource intensive. DMARC in particular can't always fit in a UDP DNS packet, it gets truncated, which can slow down queries significantly. You should also check that your NAT/firewall can handle the *extraordinary* number of connections this kind of activity can generate.

Comment: @tadman - Any recommendations on how to best investigate where the bottlenecks exists? I am seeing some DNS Timeout after digging into the logs, but it's just hitting the 1 sec timeout, which is fine.

Comment: A) Keep an eye on your TCP socket availability. In my testing I quickly "ran out" of sockets when doing mass queries. B) Run your own DNS server so you can tweak resolution rates. I used the bind9 container on Docker, it's easy to configure from there. C) You may need to split this across multiple VMs to avoid socket limits, if that's impacting you.